# RaspiOS 64 bit running much slower than 32 bit

Tags: performance, 64-bit

I have two RPi 4's running Bitcoin Core v25.0. One is 32-bit RPiOS and the other is 64-bit. 32-bit / 64-bit ARM versions of Bitcoin Core are installed respectively. Both computers are fitted with the same make/model of USB SSD drive for Bitcoin data. What could be causing this huge performance discrepancy?

Here's the specs of the two systems:

### 32 bit

```
$ uname -a
Linux zippi 5.10.103-v8+ #1529 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 8 12:26:46 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ getconf LONG_BIT
32

$ file `which bitcoind`
/usr/local/bin/bitcoind: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

### 64 bit

```
$ uname -a
Linux blockclock 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ getconf LONG_BIT
64

$ file `which bitcoind`
/usr/local/bin/bitcoind: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped
```

However, I am very surprised to see the performance on the 64-bit setup is much worse than the 32-bit system, by a factor of at least 10x. The following is the `bench` output from Bitcoin Core's debug log on each system as they process the same block.

### 32 bit

```
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]   - Using cached block
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]   - Load block from disk: 0.10ms [0.61s (0.56ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]     - Sanity checks: 0.01ms [0.12s (0.11ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]     - Fork checks: 0.07ms [0.03s (0.03ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]       - Connect 2252 transactions: 93.99ms (0.042ms/tx, 0.010ms/txin) [769.89s (704.38ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]     - Verify 9470 txins: 94.15ms (0.010ms/txin) [775.95s (709.93ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]     - Write undo data: 33.30ms [31.67s (28.98ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]     - Index writing: 0.12ms [0.02s (0.02ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]   - Connect total: 129.61ms [809.13s (740.28ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]   - Flush: 37.03ms [37.14s (33.98ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:51Z [bench]   - Writing chainstate: 0.18ms [0.04s (0.04ms/blk)]
```

### 64 bit

```
2023-10-15T11:30:52Z [bench]   - Using cached block
2023-10-15T11:30:52Z [bench]   - Load block from disk: 1.16ms [87.55s (237.27ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:52Z [bench]     - Sanity checks: 1.74ms [6.19s (16.72ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:52Z [bench]     - Fork checks: 19.49ms [6.00s (16.20ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:53Z [bench]       - Connect 2252 transactions: 1096.46ms (0.487ms/tx, 0.116ms/txin) [9787.89s (26453.75ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:53Z [bench]     - Verify 9470 txins: 1099.27ms (0.116ms/txin) [9794.32s (26471.12ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:53Z [bench]     - Write undo data: 22.48ms [33.33s (90.09ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:53Z [bench]     - Index writing: 0.50ms [0.55s (1.48ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:53Z [bench]   - Connect total: 1146.92ms [9860.73s (26650.62ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:54Z [bench]   - Flush: 737.86ms [440.64s (1190.91ms/blk)]
2023-10-15T11:30:54Z [bench]   - Writing chainstate: 0.18ms [0.59s (1.59ms/blk)]
```

for @jaromanda-x the lsusb outputs:

### 32 bit

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04e8:4001 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1997:2433
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

### 64 bit

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04e8:4001 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd PSSD T7
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3151:3000 YICHIP Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Comment: are there any messages in `dmesg` regarding the drive? I found [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8764153.html?sid=8046c484a2e17c492961c90b5359701b) regarding the same device. Don't know what kernel version they were running, but they hoped to fix it by upgrading to 6.1 ... so ... there may well be some issue in the driver after kernel 5.10

Comment: not sure if it's possible for you to do this ... have you tried swapping the drives? it may be that the one on the 64bit system is "faulty" in some way!